# Celery's pytest fixtures (celery_worker and celery_app) does not work

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to write a Celery(v. 4.2.1) integration test for my Django(v. 2.2.3) application.

There is a bunch of outdated articles about this around, but non of them seem to use stuff from the latest celery testing documentation - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.2.1/userguide/testing.html#fixtures

Seems like Celery comes with two fixtures for testing: `celery_app` and `celery_worker` which should allow to actually run worker in the background thread of your tests.

As the doc's say I've added

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': 'memory://',
        'result_backend': 'rpc'
    }
```

into my `conftest.py`

I've wrapped my test function with

```
@pytest.mark.celery_app
@pytest.mark.celery_worker
```

usually I wrap my celery tasks with

```
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task
def blabla(...):
    pass
```

but I've even tried to replace it with

```
from myapp.celery import celery
@celery.task
def blabla():
    pass
```

What else... I run my celery task via `apply_async` providing `eta` argument.

Tried tons of ways but the celery fixtures do not affect how things work and the task call goes to actual redis instance and is picked by a worker in a separate process (if I run it) and hence my `assert_called` fails along with my efforts to access the object which are in the testing database.

This way it it does not load fixtures.
[image]

This way it does not use specified fixtures because they should appear in the method arguments and break it by exceeding the number of arguments.

[image]

Thought that the Celery pytest plugin might be missing at all, but that's not true - tried to register it explicitly:
[image]

Though the fixtures are available to pytest:
[image]

But I've got into theis source code, added some wild `prints` there and I don't see them logged.

Answer (score 18):

OP here, I've figured it out and wrote an article - https://medium.com/@scythargon/how-to-use-celery-pytest-fixtures-for-celery-intergration-testing-6d61c91775d9

Main key:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_app')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('celery_session_worker')
class MyTest():
    def test(self):
        assert mul.delay(4, 4).get(timeout=10) == 16
```

Comment: The mock idea is simple and works, celery should have an easy way to test

Comment: Do you have any simple project example of your decision? Can't get the result code form the article

Answer (score 4):

For how many developers use these tools, I'm surprised at how lacking the docs are on the topic. I struggled with this for about a half day and then found [@scythargon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531116/scythargon)'s discussion. I solved it slightly differently, so I'm throwing my answer in the the mix for posterity (very close to the OP's method):

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@shared_task()
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

pytest_plugins = ('celery.contrib.pytest', )

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': 'redis://localhost:8001',
        'result_backend': 'redis://localhost:8001'
    }
```

**tests.py**

```
from api.app.tasks import add, multiply

def test_celery_worker_initializes(celery_app, celery_worker):
    assert True


def test_celery_tasks(celery_app, celery_worker):

    assert add.delay(4, 4).get(timeout=5) == 8
    assert multiply.delay(4, 4).get(timeout=5) == 16
```

As an added bonus, my `redis` broker and backend are running in Docker (as part of a swarm):

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  . . .

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      swarm-net:
        aliases:
          - redis
    ports:
      - "8001:6379"

  . . .
```

Comment: If one is using rabbitmq-server , how can kombu from celery make connection with rabbitmq-server without starting the live server(rabbit) on the local machine ? and how can this be replicated on github ci.yml since running the test there cause similar issue

Comment: Your answer seems to work fine with tasks created with `@shared_task`. How do you test a task created with `@app.task` where `app` is a Celery app?

Comment: I have posted my question with more details @ https://stackoverflow.com/q/75217488/4635580