# Pytest with Celery tasks works but shows "ERROR in consumer: Received unregistered task of type X"

Tags: python, celery, pytest

I have Pytest working to test Celery tasks based on this Stack Overflow Q&A: [Celery's pytest fixtures (celery_worker and celery_app) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59075969/1164465).

**conftest.py**

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_config():
    return {
        "broker_url": REDIS_URL,
        "result_backend": REDIS_URL,
    }
```

Tests are passing with the configuration below:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_app")
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_worker")
class TestMyCeleryTask:

    def test_run_task(self) -> None:
        ...
```

All of the tests are passing. However, no matter what order I import the Celery App and/or my tasks, I always receive the following output:

```
ERROR in consumer: Received unregistered task of type 'my_celery_task'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.
```

Note that I am using the old-school class-based Task approach rather than using the decorator to convert functions into classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever Celery Pytest fixture is being used to obtain a Celery App instance, that particular instance needs to have the Celery tasks registered.

In this case, you are using the Celery session instance:

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_app")
```

To register your Celery task for all tests, you could add the following to "conftest.py".

**conftest.py**

```py
import pytest
from my_application import MyCeleryTask


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_app")
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_worker")
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def celery_register_tasks(celery_session_app):
    celery_session_app.register_task(MyCeleryTask)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_config():
    return {
        "broker_url": REDIS_URL,
        "result_backend": REDIS_URL,
    }
```