# How to test the tasks of a Celery instance using pytest?

Tags: celery, celery-task

How to test the tasks of a Celery instance using pytest? I am not talking about testing the Celery tasks created using the `@shared_task` decorator with pytest. For that, there is already [a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063784/4635580). I am talking about testing tasks created with the `app.task` decorator where `app` is a Celery app, a `Celery` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me. `celery_worker.reload()` re-registries the task.

```
def test_xxx(celery_app, celery_worker):
    @celery_app.task
    def mul(x, y):
        return x * y

    celery_worker.reload()
    assert mul.delay(4, 4).get(timeout=10) == 16
```

Comment: This example works, but it doesn't do any testing of my own code.

Comment: oh. you probably need to look into the `Task.bind(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I could not locate any official docs on this. Below is a summary from some of my experiments.

My versions

```
celery[pytest]==5.3.6
pytest==7.4.3
```

The basics: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/testing.html

The `celery_worker` could be configured like below.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_worker_parameters():
    return {"without_heartbeat": True}
```

Look at https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/contrib/testing/worker.py#L155 for `celery_worker_parameters` hints.

How does this work? `celery_worker` includes `celery_worker_parameters` fixture in its signature. See https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/contrib/pytest.py#L199 and  https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/contrib/pytest.py#L160

You could try the below approach to configuring the `celery_app` and see if it works for you:

```
@pytest.mark.celery(
  broker_url="memory://localhost:8000/"
)
def test_how_to_use_celery_app_and_worker(
  celery_app,
  celery_worker,
)
```

Celery loads the mark and configures itself. See here: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/contrib/pytest.py#L72

My test env has some constraints. I used a fixture in `conftest.py` for `celery_app` configuration.

```
@pytest.fixture
def os_environ_celery_app_cfg():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {
        "CELERY_BROKER_URL": "memory://localhost:8000/",
    }) as mock_environ:
        yield mock_environ
```

See https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/app/utils.py#L103 for hints about these env vars.

My unit test:

```
def test_how_to_use_celery_app_and_worker(
  os_environ_celery_app_cfg,
  celery_app,
  celery_worker,
)

  @celery_app.task(bind=True) # ** ensure @celery_app prefix **
  def my_worker(self: Task, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

  celery_worker.reload() # ** call after task declaration **

  my_worker.apply_async()
```

It is important that `celery_worker.reload()` is called after the async task is declared. This is because the Celery Strategy for this task needs to be reconfigured. See https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/worker/worker.py#L273

Also, ensure that the task decorator has the `@celery_app` prefix:

```
@celery_app.task
```

The async task in the unit test will run in the worker thread.  Any effects / benefits introduced by unit test fixtures will not be available in the worker thread.

If you have a Celery shared_task implemented elsewhere, you could still use above approach in your unit test with some tweaks.  You may not have to call `reload()` depending on how your code is structured. If `celery_worker` is invoked, it will automatically invoke `celery_app`. You cannot avoid it. See https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/da1146ab60065847b9742bb61190d52a7a2c5fdf/celery/contrib/pytest.py#L196